# A verb for increasing the sales?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want a verb that means "to increase the sales" of a product. For example, what to put in the blank in the following sentence?

> That is just an advertisement that is intended to ... (of the
>   product).

Comment: What's wrong with *increase the sales*?

Comment: If you want to increase sales by selling the same customer an additional or more expensive product, you could say **upsell**.

Comment: A very common word to use in connection with the aim of promotion is "boost", "to boost" sales. I'm reluctant to use it as an answer because you can boost things other than sales (you would need to use both the word 'boost' and 'sales') en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boost

Comment: ...grow the sales.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the word you want is **drive**.

I'm guessing that you want something other than "increasing the sales" or "promoting the product", both of which are good straightforward answers.

If you're looking for a professional vocabulary, as opposed to ad copy like growing a love for fertilizer or creating an appetite for chicken nuggets, here's something to consider:

An increase in sales comes from action by the seller, who naturally wants to get the best return on their marketing and communications investment. There's also something called the McKinsey Consumer Decision Journey and the Loyalty Loop, which many people see as a useful model for encouraging repeat business. A consumer can be reached at multiple points, and at each point the possibility exists of encouraging them to spend more. The right word for your purpose of increasing sales will depend on how the seller imagines the potential customer, how they are being reached, and where they are on their individual journey.

The word you want may be a specific term related to one or more of the following general ideas: You can attract and inform potential buyers. You can help them decide. You can draw them into your loyalty loop. You can reward them for influencing others.

But in the end, if you're hoping to get paid, you need to **drive** sales.

Answer (score 2):

The advertisement is intended to *promote* the product.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promote):

> to present (merchandise) for buyer acceptance through advertising,
>   publicity, or discounting

If you're looking for a negative connotation, another possibility is *[push](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promote).*

> to make aggressive efforts to sell

This might be better because it works without the need for a qualifier: "That is just an advertisement that is intended to *push* Tide laundry detergent."

Comment: Aren't all ads _promoting_ something?

Comment: @alwayslearning: Arguably, that is only the case because negative advertising is illegal (as it is considered slander). You can argue that your product is superior, but not that another product is inferior (even if they are logically equivalent, e.g. if only two options exist). However, semantic definition does not assume legality, so negative advertising should be considered possible. By the way, going by American standard, I would argue that political ads that criticize the opponent are a form of negative advertisements. They are quite dramatic about it, to my European standard.